# oracle 11g beginner - how to display data from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Complete beginner to Oracle 11g here.

If I have two tables, with some overlapping attributes but no relation, how do I display all the data in one table?

Example:

```
TABLE A has a PK, a fname, lname.  
TABLE B has a PK, a fname, lname, phone.
```

I'd like to display the contents of `TABLE A` and `TABLE B` in one table.

I thought I could use a `UNION`, but you have to have the same number of columns; and since `TABLE B` has 3 columns, I get an error: `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns.`

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I (for one) am unclear on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a "fake" column into the select for TableA so that two two sets line up:

```
select PK, fname, lname, null as phone from TableA
union all 
select PK, fname, lname, phone from TableB
```

This would effectively merge the two tables.

Comment: Thanks - but in my real problem, I have 5 more columns in TABLE B that need to be displayed as well.  It doesn't seem proper to add in multiple 'null as' - but I could be wrong.

Comment: If you don't have any attribute to connect the tables by and want to display them as one set then union all with null values for the missing columns is the way to go. The alternative would be to display them side by side, but if the sets are disjoint I don't see the point of that.

Comment: Also note that the only difference between UNION (referenced in the question) and UNION ALL (used in this answer) is that UNION will be more expensive to run, but it will collapse duplicates.

Comment: For UNION ALL, I get the same error:  ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns.

To do this I am running the following:
select PK, fname, lname FROM TABLEA
UNION ALL
select PK, fname,lname,phone FROM TABLEB

This throws the error referenced.

Just to be clear, are you stating that I need to run this as your original answer, whereby I have to list out "null as <columnname>" for each column that is missing from one table to the other?

I'm trying to understand how to represent this with relational algebra as well.

Comment: @robsybobsy Yes, that's because you excluded the fake phone column with the null value from the select on TableA. The purpose of the empty column is to make sure the number of fields match.